# Find and extract an html tag from a large page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, performance, parsing

Figuring a very long html page as a string. How to extract a tag with its content? Any long Wikipedia page illustrates the thing

Using a parser like cheerio is excluded for performance reasons. Using any technique that will parse the entire page is excluded too for performance reasons. (like the `already existing` answers, please read the question before saying it's a duplicate).

The start position is easily found with `indexOf("<div class='selector'>");`

The issue is with the end position.

How to find where is the closing `</div>`, based on the start tag position? There is a lot of other div inside.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack and with CSS selector?

Comment: Not possible with JS regex.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack.  Don't use regex for parsing HTML.  You'll have a bad time, and many of us here at SO will be sad.  Don't make us sad.

Comment: Some other engines can do this. Regex is going to struggle to do the tag balance thing usisng JS, but PCRE, Perl, etc.. can do this. Can those be used ? If just parsing tags alone, JS can be used, however the script will need to maintain a stack within a callback. Let me know if you need that.

Comment: The stack is just a counter.

Comment: Even within JS, you can use the DOM to parse HTML, using the `DOMParser` class.

Comment: Why not show him how to do it @Amy

Comment: are there another DIV tags nested inside the `<div class='selector'>`? or you mean **inside** the document?

Comment: @x15 I don't feel like taking the time to write a good answer, and the OP hasn't responded to any comments yet.  You can if you wish.

Comment: Please provide a ***"html page as a string"*** example and explain what you've tried already.

Comment: DOMParser or any solution parsing the entire page is excluded. For performance reasons. It took 250ms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works well in 3ms instead of using a parser 250ms. **Parsing all the document is really not needed.**

```js
const findTag = (body, tagStart, tagName) => {
  const startIndex = body.indexOf(tagStart)
  if (startIndex === -1) return

  const endIndex = findEndIndex(body, startIndex, tagName)
  return body.substring(startIndex, endIndex)
}

const findEndIndex = (body, startIndex, tagName) => {
  const starting = `<${tagName}`
  const closing = `</${tagName}`

  let index = startIndex + 1
  let level = 1

  do {
    const nextStartPosition = body.indexOf(starting, index)
    const nextClosingPosition = body.indexOf(closing, index)
    level += nextClosingPosition < nextStartPosition ? -1 : 1
    index = Math.min(nextClosingPosition, nextStartPosition) + 1
  } while (level !== 0)

  return index + 2 + tagName.length//to include end tag in substr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Raw javascript scrapage: (I put some inner SPAN tags within the finder element.

```
var htmlString = "<body><h1>Welcome</h1><div class='wrapper'><div>Some content here<div class='selector'>This is the element <span>you <title>want</title> to </span>extract</div></div></div></body>";

var finder = "<div class='selector'>";
var AhtmlString = htmlString.split(finder);

var back = AhtmlString[1].split("</");
var countInside = back[0].split("<"); // count how many internal tags there are
var backClose = back[countInside.length].split(">")[0]; // get the closing tag name (it'll be the first one of the last one we counted

console.log(finder + back.slice(0, countInside.length).join("</") + "</" + backClose + ">");
```

Comment: I would like to measure it against my solution but I was not able to set your function passing my tests. Since I am ok my mine I won't investigate more.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you really just have a string of HTML, not an actual page with that HTML parsed.

You can easily solve the problem by loading up a temporary element with that HTML string (but never actually include it in the DOM) and then extract the part you need using the DOM API, rather than `string` methods.

Here's a scaled down example:

```js
let htmlString = "<body><h1>Welcome</h1><div class='wrapper'><div>Some content here<div class='selector'>This is the element you want to extract</div></div></div></body>";

// Load the html string up into a temporary object that isn't part of the DOM
let temp = document.createElement("div");
temp.innerHTML = htmlString;

// Now use the DOM API to extract what you need:
let part = temp.querySelector("div.selector");

// Use outerHTML to get the tag iteself along with its contents
console.log(part.outerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks you Scott, I am not using a browser but node.